# Regression model where errors are not normally distributed

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis, measurement-error

From a Physics equation I have the following model:

$$W=\beta_0+\beta_1Z$$

$\beta_0$, $\beta_1$ are fixed values for which I want to find a $1-\alpha$ confidence region.

I have $(z_1,w_1),(z_2,w_2),\ldots,(z_n,w_n)$ observations.

I get these observations from evaluating the function $f: \mathbf{R}^{l+k+2}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^2$.

$$f\left(X_1,\ldots,X_l,Y_{1i},\ldots, Y_{ki},P_{1i},P_{2i}\right)=\left(f_1\left(\ldots\right),f_2\left(\ldots\right)\right)=(Z_i,W_i),$$

where $X_j\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_j,\sigma^2)$ $Y_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta_{ij},\sigma^2)$ $P_{ik}\sim\mathcal{N}(p_{ik},\frac{p_{ik}}{1000})$; $\sigma^2$ is known, but not $\mu_j,\theta_{ji},p_{ji}.$

$X,Y,P$ are measures from an electronic instrument.

The equation $w_i=\beta_0+\beta_1z_i$ holds when $\left(z_i,w_i\right)=f\left(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_l,\theta_{1i},\ldots,\theta{ki},p_{1i},p_{2i}\right)$ ($\bf{not}$ when $\left(z_i,w_i\right)=\mathbf{E}(f(\ldots))$

Note that there are both common $\left(X_j\right)$ and not common variables $\left(Y_{ji} , P_{ki}\right)$ for all observations. Still It happens that $Y_{ji}=Y_{st}$ and $P_{1i}=P_{2t}$ for some $j$ $i$ $s$ and $t$. (Meaning that variables $Y$ and $P$ are used for more than one observation, but not all)

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are rational functions. Both numerators and denominators are quadratic functions when restricted to one variable. They are well defined.

So, **what can i do to get confidence regions for $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$?**

A regression model and Maximum Likelihood techniques are tempting.

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & z_1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 & z_n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_n \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

$\bf{\epsilon}=\bf{W-\beta_1Z-\beta_0}$   (Is this right?)

As $(Z,W)$ has a complicated joint distribution, so does $\bf{\epsilon}$.

I can figure out what to do when each $(Z_i,W_i)\sim\mathcal{N_2}((z_i,w_i),\sum)$. But this is not the case.

I understand that there may not be an easy answer for these questions, but if anyone can give some general tips or point me to the right literature i can work from there.

Comment: Is this the same question you asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/linear-equation-system-with-random-coefficients? If not, how does it differ? If it's the same, then please delete *this* one and edit your original.

Comment: Hi. I don't think is the same question. In my previous one i was asking how to model the problem. (For what I really aprecciate your help.) But in this one, I am asking how to find confidence interval with the model correctly stated.

Comment: You can bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Peter. I am reading about resampling residuals. It comes to me the question if independence of residuals is necesary for the method.

Comment: Why wouldn't the residuals be independent? Is the longitudinal data? Clustered data? And, even if they are dependent there are probably ways to bootstrap it properly.

Comment: @Manuel The notation is confusing to me.  There is an instrument from which you measure X,Y,P.  It looks like you only ever get one observation on each $X_1,\ldots,X_l$ and that each of these observations has a separate mean, $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_l$.  If that is true, then this problem is very difficult since you must know the means $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_l$ in order to create your variables $z_i,w_i$.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding?

Tell me what an observation is, observation in the statistical sense.  Each time (indexed by $i$?  by $i,j$?) you read the instrument, what variables do you observe?